# jQuery key press event only work in web address with # sign at the end

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, keypress

I got my first version of test website. [Links here.](http://www.fashionai.org/welcome/color-trend) You may notice on the right up corner there is a search box. If you just type a search query and click search, everything work. But if you just type a search query and press enter. It will just refresh the entire page.

FYI. You need to search available color name. Like `blue` or `red`.

However, if you click the search button first and then change query and press enter. This time it will work. You will notice the url has been added a # at the end of address.

The Js code show below. Or you can go to my page and check the resource.

```
$("#query").keyup(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
      $("a#submit").click();
    }
  });

  $('a#submit').click(function(event) {
    var query = $('#query').val()
    var url = 

    $.getJSON(url, function(json, textStatus) {
      ...};
 ...};
```

This is a Bug or how I can solve it. Thank you.

Comment: if you prevent the page refresh try `return false`

Comment: Thank you. Where to put `return false`?

Comment: end of the `$('a#submit').click()` function or use `event.preventDefult()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding preventDefault to the form submit event will stop the page from reloading. Read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

```
$('#formid').submit(function(event) { // Note that you'll need to give your form an id
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

You'll probably want both the onclick and submit events to call a function.

Comment: It works. But why the web refreshes even if I did't submit any form?

Comment: The default behavior is for the browser to submit when the user hits enter in a text field. The form has no action specified so it reloads itself.

Answer (score 0):

You need a handler func, in combination with killing the default browser action for a proper form, that's all.

The code you have on your site uses a hash (`#`) in the URL to make sure the page does not change on search (uses async XMLHttpRequest behind the scenes).

The search event, with hash, happens on `$('#search-btn').click()` only.

Now, you want submit to happen on multiple events (`click`, `keyDown/keyUp`), and not reload the page (adversely appending a `?`) in the URL (to prepare for a good ole fashioned `POST`).

We need to wrap the code in a single handler function and attach listeners where appropriate on the `click` and `keyDown/keyUp` events.

### Cleaned-up Code (ES6 - hope you don't mind...)

```
const submitHandler = (e) => {
    const query = $('#query').val() || e.target.value
    const url = 'https://api.fashion.net/colors/'

    // shorthand GET request
    $.getJSON(url, (json, textStatus) => {
        // ... do stuff with response ...
    })
    .done(() => {
        // ... do stuff when done ...
    })
    .fail(err => {
        console.log('error: ', err);
    })
}

// handle user query on 'search' click
$('#submit').click(submitHandler)

// handle user query on 'enter' pressed
// NOTE: invalidates default action
$('#query').keyDown((e) => {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        // kill browser default
        e.preventDefault()
        // run submit handler
        submitHandler(e)
        // exit
        return
    }
})
```